# scrolling to the parent div top with jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, scrolltop

I thought this would be easy.

I have the following HTML

```
<div>
<div id="child"></div>
</div>
```

I tried a couple things

```
if ($('#child').length){
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(this).parent().offset().top}, 'slow');
}
```

and

```
if ($('.success_div').length){
    pdiv = $(this).parent();
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: pdiv.offset().top}, 'slow');
}
```

error:  TypeError: pdiv.offset(...) is undefined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**How about this?**

```
if ($('#child').length){
    $('body').animate({scrollTop: $('#child').parent().offset().top},'slow');
});
```

calling an element in an if statement doesn't select it, so $(this) matches nothing inside of `if ($('#child').length){`, so i called `$('#child')` again inside of the statement.

Answer (score 0):

To scroll a child element to the top of a parent element.

```
if($('#child').length)
{
  $('#parent').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#child').offset().top - $('#parent').offset().top
  },'slow');
};
```